# Intent filter to respond to all URLs in Android?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to make an app that involves responding to all the URLs on a device. Documentation mentions how to handle a specific scheme like below-

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

But how do I define an intent filter to handle any URL not just belonging to a particular domain or host? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Define Schema like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:scheme="about"/>
    <data android:scheme="javascript"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the below line from the code you posted:

```
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http" />
```

So you will end up with

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Alternatively, you may want to just shorten the line to

```
  <data android:scheme="http" />
```

This will make your app intercept only http URLs, so basically links.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the official android tutorial says you can simply remove the data filter to make your intent-filter less restrictive, doing so might lead to "missing data element" errors.
You can do the below instead

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:host="*.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can also add data filters for .net, .org etc